# Does this variant of unrestricted comprehension fall prey to a modified Russell's paradox?

Tags: set-theory

Let us state axiom schemata *without parameters*, so as to facilitate readability, but with the understanding that we really mean **with** parameters.

Under this convention, the infamous Axiom Schema of Unrestricted Comprehension can be written follows.

$$\exists A\forall e(e \in A \leftrightarrow P(e))$$

Russell's paradox derives a contradiction from this schema. The proof is roughly as follows.

1. Substitute $P(e)$ with $e \notin e.$
   $$\exists A\forall e(e \in A \leftrightarrow e \notin e)$$
2. Let $A$ be fixed but arbitrary satisfying the above sentence.
   $$\forall e(e \in A \leftrightarrow e \notin e)$$
3. Replace $e$ with $A$.
   $$A \in A \leftrightarrow A \notin A$$

Now presumably, when this paradox was first discovered, mathematicians tried very hard to salvage unrestricted comprehension. An obvious first attempt would be:

$$\exists A\forall e(e \in A \leftrightarrow e \neq A \wedge P(e))$$

This time, we obtain

$$A \in A \leftrightarrow A \neq A \wedge A \notin A$$

which isn't contradictory, indeed we may conclude $A \notin A.$

But, I'm guessing the modified schema falls prey to some kind of "modified Russell's paradox." Ideas, anyone?

*Edit*. As aws points out in the comments, this schema is actually consistent. Consider a model with a single element $*$ and define $* \notin *$.

Thus, we should at least assume there exists a non-empty set. Feel free to use something stronger, like the existence of an infinite set.

Comment: As it stands, your axiom scheme is consistent: consider the model with one element, $\ast$, and define $\in$ by $\ast \notin \ast$. If you add the axiom $\exists x, y\; x \in y$ it might make something like Russell's paradox work. I'll think about it.

Comment: @aws, ahhh good point. This calls for an edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do something that's essentially similar to Russell's paradox, but requires a bit more work and the assumption that there are $X$ and $Y$ with $X \neq Y$. Let $A$ be such that for all $x$:
$$
x \in A \leftrightarrow (x \neq A \wedge \neg (\exists y\; y \in x \wedge x \in y))
$$

If we can only show that the singleton $\{A\}$ exists, then we can reason as follows:

Since $A \notin A$, we clearly can't have $A = \{A\}$.
Suppose $\{A\} \in A$. Then, since $A \in \{A\}$, we would have $\exists y\; y \in \{A\} \wedge \{A\} \in y$, and conclude $\{A\} \notin A$, a contradiction. Hence $\{A\} \notin A$. But now suppose that $y$ is such that $y \in \{A\}$ and $\{A\} \in y$. Since $y \in \{A\}$ we must have that $y = A$, and so $\{A\} \in A$, and so, by contradiction with $\{A\} \notin A$, we must have $\neg (\exists y\;y\in \{A\} \wedge \{A\} \in y)$. But now we can conclude $\{A\} \in A$ and finally deduce that the theory in inconsistent.

To show $\{A\}$ exists, we will show $A$ is nonempty and then apply the following lemma:

**Lemma** Suppose that $X$ is nonempty. Then there is a set $Y$ such that for all $y$, $y \in Y$ if and only if $y = X$.

**Proof** Let $Y$ be such that $y \in Y \leftrightarrow (y \neq Y \wedge y = X)$. Suppose $Y$ is empty. Then $X \notin Y$, and so we are forced to conclude $X = Y$. But $Y$ is empty and $X$ is non empty, contradiction. Hence $Y$ is nonempty, but this easily implies the result.

Now we just have to construct an element of $A$. This is also the first place where we will require "non triviality," so let's assume that there are $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \neq Y$.

Let $C$ be such that for all $x$,
$$
x \in C \leftrightarrow x \neq C
$$
Note that $C$ has to contain either $X$ or $Y$, and so $C$ can't be empty. Note also that we can construct an empty set, $E$. Since $C$ is nonempty we have $C \neq E$, and so $E \in C$.

Now let $B$ be such that for all $x$,
$$
x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \neq B \wedge \exists y \in x\;y \text{ is empty})
$$
Note that $C \neq B$ because $B$ can't contain any empty sets.
Hence $C \in B$, and so $B$ isn't empty. Hence $\{B\}$ exists by the lemma. Note that if $y \in \{B\}$ and $\{B\} \in y$, then we would have $y = B$ and so $\{B\} \in B$. But then $\{B\}$ would have to contain an empty set and so $B$ would be empty. Contradiction. Hence $\neg (\exists y \; y \in \{B\} \wedge \{B\} \in y)$. Note that if $\{B\} = A$, then we would already know that $A$ is non empty, and so we can assume $\{B\} \neq A$. But this implies $\{B\} \in A$, and so we do have that $A$ is nonempty, and so $\{A\}$ exists, resulting in the theory being inconsistent.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll fix it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm having difficulty following this argument, near the beginning. "Suppose {A}∈A. Then, since A∈{A}, we would have ∃y(y∈{A}∧{A}∈y), and conclude {A}∉A, a contradiction." How are you able to deduce a positive formula ∃y(y∈{A}∧{A}∈y)? I can see how to deduce $\neg$∃y(y∈{A}∧{A}∈y).

Comment: Deduce $\exists y(y \in \{A\}\wedge\{A\}\in y)$ by setting $y := A$ and applying the assumption that $\{A\} \in A$. This sort of thing is a bit tricky.

Comment: wait do you mean setting $x := A$?

Comment: I mean from $(A \in \{A\} \wedge \{A\}\in A)$ deduce $\exists y(y \in \{A\} \wedge \{A\} \in y)$. In other words, there is a $y$ such that $y \in \{A\} \wedge \{A\} \in y$, because $A$ is an example of such a $y$. Then $x := \{A\}$ cannot satisfy $x \neq A \wedge \neg (\exists y(x \in y \wedge y \in x))$, so $\{A\} \notin A$.

Comment: Ahaha okay... finally makes sense !